# Font is bigger than 'element' around it

Tags: html, css, text, containers, font-size

I experienced, that if I set a specific p tags font-size to let's say 55px the actual element which contains the font is smaller than the font itself.

Therefor the font is overlapping the elements above.
Of course I can set some padding there, but why is the - i call it 'imaginary' object, because it's just made by my browser - not getting the same size as the content - in this case the font?
By the way, this 'imaginary' container has always the same height. does not matter if the p-text has a size of 12px or 55px. In my case this height is always 15px...

thanks for hints about this matter.

cheers

Comment: there is not really a problem. I just wondered why this is like this & if I maybe made some mistake in my html/css

Comment: Somebody downvoted my answer, cmon !! :D I just offered a bounty +250 `do not be such a critic` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to reduce line-height:

```
.imaginary {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

Comment: That exactly what I just found out. I hade a line-height defined in my body {} which says: line-height: 15px;

Comment: Gustonez can you upvote my answer, I will upvote yours, I say so because I have to offer another bounty question :D

Comment: i wonder why someone could vote down for my correct answer because they didn't understand what line-height really do! :-D

Comment: :D I never said that I was answering still someone downvoted me :D

Comment: i didn't down-vote your answer because i don't have more than 125 points!! not me.

Comment: I never said you downvoted haha :D I begged to upvote my answer because I have to offer a bounty, please it will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

This indirectly/directly influences your answer:

```
  <style>
    html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, img, ol, ul,
    li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      border:0;
      font-size:100%;
      font:inherit;
      vertical-align:baseline;
    }
  </style>
```

So, make sure that you atleast have the above lines of code whenever you work with css.

Comment: Sorry I bothered you all here with this stupid questions.
thanks for the answers anyway.
cheers